# Installing an event source for an ASPNET Core 2.2 webapi application

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, event-log, serilog

I need some help understanding what needs to be done to deploy an aspnet core webapi application to a server so that the event sink is properly installed without needing to run the application as administrator.

In the development environment, Visual Studio running as administrator can launch my aspnet core webapi application allowing it to create an event sink on the local machine. Once the event sink has been created the application will log events even if the application is not launched with admin privileges.

When the application is published to a test server and running under IIS, the application fails to load if the logging is configured to create the event source if not present on the local machine.

I am using Serilog with the Serilog.Sinks.EventLog extension.

When manageEventSource is set to true, the application does not load because it can't create the event source. When manageEventSource is set to false the application loads correctly but no events are sent to the EventLog.

```
        Log.Logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
          .MinimumLevel.Debug()
          .MinimumLevel.Override("Microsoft", LogEventLevel.Information)
          .Enrich.FromLogContext()
          .WriteTo.Console()
          .WriteTo.File("webservices-log.txt", rollingInterval: RollingInterval.Day)
          .WriteTo.EventLog("WebServices", manageEventSource: false, restrictedToMinimumLevel: LogEventLevel.Error)
          .CreateLogger();
```

When Visual Studio is finished publishing I need the application to run and log Errors to the event log, but if the event sink is not already installed the application fails unless directed to ignore the creation step. How can I update the publish step to install the Event Sink on the target machine, or What do I need to do to manually intervene before publishing to the target?